# Bootstrap 3 - expand collapsed table row smoothly

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, expand

(please forgive my ignorance I'm not a coder)

Here's my [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aNJwPQ)

I'm having trouble with a table of items, where I want to hide a div with the descriptions, unless user clicks on the row for the specific item.

So I almost got it working as I want, using `class="collapse"` - but the animation is not smooth.

Then I tried using `class="accordion-toggle"`- now it's smooth but 1. I don't want to have it as accordion (I want the user to be able to expand all descriptions)- even though it doesn't behave like one, 2. it is revealing some portion the row below, which I want to hide when the row is collapsed.

**note**:
I modified default bootstrap table as I wanted higher rows without border, by:

```
    td {
    height:50px;
    border:none!important;
    vertical-align:middle!important;
}
```

**Additional Question:**
I also want to have the table striped, but my descriptions break it because they are in every other row (how to prevent that?)

Here's what I want to achieve:
 [image: Table with collapsed row with description]

Comment: The striped effect won't work because of the `hiddenRows`. I don't think a table is the best approach for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

### Try this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Accordion Example</h2>
  <p><strong>Note:</strong> The <strong>data-parent</strong> attribute makes sure that all collapsible elements under the specified parent will be closed when one of the collapsible item is shown.</p>
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Collapsible Group 1</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Collapsible Group 2</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Collapsible Group 3</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

### for strip table

```
<div class="panel-group">
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Collapsible list group</a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item">One</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Two</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Three</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="panel-footer">Footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you clearly didn't even read the post. Copying pasting example straight from bootstrap documentation is not gonna help.

Comment: Sorry i did not saw your additonal question.Could you please share your code? So i can help you.

Comment: If i am not wrong what i understood..you need to hide the table hiddenrow. But they available and visible with table strip.I am new for the stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

use this may be it will help you.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.hiddenRow').css('display','none');
  $('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){
    $('.hiddenRow').toggle();
  })
});
```

Comment: Could you please edit my codepen and save it, then paste here the link to updated codepen?

Comment: this is only js code.
<scripty type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.hiddenRow').css('display','none');
  $('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){
    $('.hiddenRow').toggle();
  })
});
</script>
you just need to add this code in you head. rest of code remains same.